# Error when trying to Move Figure Legend in MatplotLib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I'm trying to move my figure legend to the best location on my figure so it's not blocking my charts. I've tried both `fig.legend` as well as `plt.figlegend()` but both keep returning this error (I should mention that the number of plots can range from 2-20 - so I cant just anchor to the bottom right or something along those lines):

> UserWarning: Automatic legend placement (loc="best") not implemented for figure legend. Falling back on "upper right".
>     warnings.warn('Automatic legend placement (loc="best") not '

[image]

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. The message is fairly clear I think. For a figure-level legend, there is no implemented way to automatically place the legend at the "best" location , you'll have to choose the placement yourself, or make room in your figure to place the legend regardless of the number of subplots

Comment: how can I make room to place it regardless of the number of subplots?

Comment: the subplots are created via a loop so I add via:ax = fig.add_subplot(int(sqrt(self.no_splits)), int(sqrt(self.no_splits)+1), i)

Comment: refer to [the answer by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/1356000) particularly the part about Figure-level legend, and the use of `subplots_adjust()` to make room for the legend

Comment: As long as `self.no_splits` is not a square number itself, you have space for the legend at the last subplot position which isn't filled. If `no_splits` is a square number, you need to increase the number of rows by 1 and put the legend there.